# I don't have any idea, what to do with this post

Tags: discussion, flagging

It is about the now probably deleted post [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/37031/4788). The post essentially advertises a site where cheap native speakers can be hired for training.

The first reaction is that it is obvious spam.

There is probably a very big need for similar services, and it is obviously not reachable for free. Thus, asking any of them, or mentioning any of them would fall unavoidably on the spam rules.

Second, it is useful... probably I will hire one of them. I couldn't even imagine that it is possible so cheaply.

I think, such answers aren't allowed on the general spam ban of the SE. But somewhere, somehow, some resources should be collected which can be really useful for many visitors.

Maybe similar things and resources could be collected in meta post(s)?

Comment: [Here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/70699) is a Metasmoke archive, for context once that post gets deleted.

Comment: The post was deleted for containing spam. The (extremely poor) service advertised is a known spammer. They did it several times before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's spam.

It doesn't attempt to answer the question, and only serves to advertise the service.

Comment: Also, preply is a known-spam website -- Metasmoke has [85 spam posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=✓&title=&body=preply.com&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) from them.

Answer (score 3):

> Second, it is useful... probably I will hire one of them. I couldn't even imagine that it is possible so cheaply.

I don’t know about this particular service, but spam is often not only unsolicited, but also false advertisement.

Comment: I had a look at that service on the first spam wave they posted here. It was  **entirely useless** then.